# HAProxy stick-table

Tags: haproxy

in HAProxy I'm trying to track connections to a certain page with a random key value. The configuration I'm using is:

```
stick-table type string size 200 store gpc0
acl test_page url_reg -i test.php 
tcp-request inspect-delay 30s
tcp-request content track-sc1 rand if test_page
```

Entries are in fact added to the stick-table:

```
# table: varnish_cluster-01, type: string, size:200, used:10
0x2f05d54: key=1191905894 use=0 exp=0 gpc0=0
0x2ec4524: key=1588367676 use=0 exp=0 gpc0=0
0x34e3ab4: key=1768543047 use=0 exp=0 gpc0=0
0x3b3cd94: key=1938692325 use=0 exp=0 gpc0=0
0x380bcf4: key=2016928663 use=0 exp=0 gpc0=0
0x39535e4: key=2095442698 use=0 exp=0 gpc0=0
0x3cb3824: key=396763764 use=0 exp=0 gpc0=0
0x39d6644: key=500760259 use=0 exp=0 gpc0=0
0x3994e14: key=945137186 use=0 exp=0 gpc0=0
0x34a2284: key=995489922 use=0 exp=0 gpc0=0
```

But I'm getting an empty response from the backend.

Any idea why?

I'm trying to achieve what I describe here: [HAProxy/Varnish: redirecting a percentage of traffic](https://serverfault.com/questions/694732/haproxy-varnish-redirecting-a-percentage-of-traffic)

Comment: What's in your haproxy logs when you're doing this? Also try enabling debug logging for more info.